# Trying to find count of missed targets between 2 sheets

Tags: excel, boolean, algebra

I am trying to work through this problem where I have 2 sheets (seen here as 2 sections for simplicity) and I am trying to count how many shipments from sheet 1 were below the SLA target in sheet 2.

The formula I tried was

`IF(A21=INDEX(A2:A11,MATCH(A21,A2:A11,0),COUNTIF(C2:C11, ">="&C21))`

I have tried multiple iterations of these parameters and have it returning some very inconsistent and totally wrong results. The output I am expecting is

0,0,1,3,0,0

I know this is going to probably be some kind of boolean algebra but I honestly do not understand how that system works. I have tried looking it up but I dont think i am doing it right.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOznF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple boolean multiplier like this:

```
=SUM((A21=$A$2:$A$11)*($C$2:$C$11<C21))
```

This checks if the ID matches A21 and then multiplies these TRUE/FALSE results times a second boolean array that checks if the shipped amounts (C2:C11) are less than the SLA standard C21.  *NB: If it is really less than or equal, then use `=SUM((A21=$A$2:$A$11)*($C$2:$C$11<=C21))`.*  This generates a series of 1's for each value that matches the conditions and then SUM adds those one's up.

Using your example for ID Key 4/Item Name D, you would get:

```
SUM({FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE} * {TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE})
```

This gets coerced into:

```
SUM({0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0})
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much. So how did you know to use *? Also, is there any difference between* and / when doing these boolean algebraic equations?

Comment: Hey - you were right about the idea of Boolean Algebra. It works on the principle TRUE=1 & FALSE=0 which makes AND=* (multiply) and OR=+ (add). Using that logic, you just make your conditions into simpler algebraic formulas, where you ask is A2:A11=A21 and then AND(*) that with is C2*C11<C21. The alternative is to use an IF statement, but it becomes easy to get lost in the semantics (at least for me) when using a range. Your intuition to apply INDEX was right, but it works on ranges as arrays whereas COUNTIF aggregates, so applying them together gets messy. SUM lets you keep it simple.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. So does this kind of operation work with any arithmetic function? Also are * and + the only 2 operations or do - and / have roles as well?

Sorry for these basic questions, this is a whole new world to me. Literally programming in a normal language would be easier...lol.

Comment: Yes, in fact, it is a way to eliminate IF functions where that is useful§. The - and / operators do work on boolean values, in fact, when applied, they "coerce" the values into integers of 1 & 0, but they do not have a boolean operator equivalent (tmk). Together, with NOT, the + and * can create nearly any boolean operator, but in numerical form. For example, XOR is the equivalent of `=OR(AND(A1,NOT(A2)),AND(NOT(A1),A2))` which is numerically `= A1*NOT(A2) + NOT(A1)*A2 `. A1 and A2 can be replaced compare operators (<=>) and with equally dimensioned ranges to generate of range of 0/1 results.

Comment: § the caveat is that IF can serve a very useful purpose as well. For example, this formula returns the last row number in a range where a cell contains "dog": `=MAX(ROW(A1:A6)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH("dog",A1:A6)))`. But if you want the first row number, changing the MAX to MIN will fail because the FALSEs become zeros. So, IF is the better approach, like this: `=MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("dog",A1:A6)),ROW(A1:A6)))`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is insanely helpful.

What do you mean by the / and - coerce the values?

Comment: When you force a cell's data type to change from Bool to Number inside a formula, it is called "coercion". e.g. `=TRUE*TRUE` coerces the result to 1 whereas if you simply used a boolean function such as AND(TRUE,TRUE), your result would be TRUE, so it would remain in the same data type.  Whenever you multiply, add, subtract or divide boolean values, you are coercing them into numerical values. Sometimes, you will see a formula like `=SUM(--(A1>B1:B10))`. This is a form of coercion. As there is nothing to multiply it against, you can take the -. Do it twice to keep the signs correct.

Comment: Hi Mark,

Do you know if it is possible to do an INDEX Match with an AND OR criteria match condition?

Comment: That is a broad context, but yes, as an example: `INDEX([some range of values], MATCH(TRUE, [some boolean formula],0),...)` would search for the first TRUE result in a boolean formula applied to a range. An example, might be give the first city, country, GDP etc. for any city where it is a national capital and has at least 10% of the nation's population. It would (probably) result in Andorra la Vella, but while Luxembourg, Singapore, Vaduz, Vatican City, etc. would also qualify, they would never be selected.

Comment: Thank you so much Mark. I am sorry for the lack of detail, I did have a post on here but these sites are so finicky with cross-posting I didn't want to get yelled at.  Thank you very much for the help. I managed to figure it out through the reddit.

=INDEX(A1:D4,MATCH(1,(A1:A4=A11)*IF(((B1:B4=B11)+(C1:C4=B11))>1,1,((B1:B4=B11)+(C1:C4=B11))),0),4)